# Malicious Bots waking up heroku free app and using up all dyno hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bots

I have an app hosted on heroku which for the last 5 years has done fine on free dyno hours. There's a single user, and it doesn't get much use throughout the day.

As of the last couple of months, we seem to be targeted by bots who created fake accounts. we are getting so many of these bots now, that they are waking our app up so often that it has consumed our free dyno hours.

Does anyone know how to get rid of them? I had tried using invisible_captcha but that did not seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider to use RackAttack https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

It's a middleware that allows you to block/allow a request.
For example, if they are using the same email domain for each new registration, you  could only accept ten registrations (because it's not a big website) with this domain by hour, until they calm down.

Or, if they come from the same place, you can limit the requests of this country thanks to their IP

EDIT:
If you check the country based on the IP address, the dyno will be wake up (because you'll call an external service to get the information), so it's not a good solution in this case

Comment: But wouldn't that still wake up the dyno?

Comment: @Eyeslandic On this page (https://www.heroku.com/dynos) they say that the application receives a web request then the request is delivered to a random web dyno. It will be okay because the middleware will be executed before, and RackAttack will "kill" bad requests

Comment: @escanxr I'm pretty sure it will still wake up the dyno and be chargeable, the ruby code has to run somewhere

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**
If you have only a single user, consider hosting the app on a secret subdomain which will not get crawled. And everytime you get an issue like this you can just change your subdomain and inform your user.

**A more complex solution:**
Use a solution like [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com) and prevent unwanted traffic to the application.